# Regex to reject if all numbers and reject colon

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am trying for a regex to

- reject if input is all numbers
- accept alpha-neumeric
- reject colon ':'

I tried ,

`ng-pattern="/[^0-9]/"` and

```
ng-pattern="/[^0-9] [^:]*$/"
```

for example ,

"**Block1 Grand-street USA**" must be accepted

"**111132322**" must be rejected

"**Block 1 grand :** " must be rejected

Comment: Please give some test cases.

Comment: @Toto added some use cases above

Comment: See my answer, does it work for you?

Comment: @Toto your answers is the one which works to an extent but it rejects all special characters

Comment: I recommend checking https://regex101.com/r/b8KOtz/2 and https://regex101.com/r/b8KOtz/3 (my regex demos) - and if they do not work for some reason, the best you can do is share your current code that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!\d+$)[^:]+$/"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8KOtz/2).

To only forbid a `:` at the end of the string, use

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!\d+$)(?:.*[^:])?$/"
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8KOtz/3)

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d+$)` - no 1+ digits to the end of the string
- `[^:]+` - one or more chars other than `:`
- `(?:.*[^:])?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `[^:]` - any char other than `:` (if you do not want to match an empty string, replace the `(?:` and `)?`)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I like your approach with `(?!\d+$)` better, but you should probably add `(?!.*?:)` to reject colons.

Comment: not accepting space and other special characters other than colon are not accepted

Comment: @sajanyamaha Sorry, there was a long line at the post office. I updated the answer and added some other options.

Comment: some cahnge in requirement came in .now should allow ' , / -' and reject all other special characters so i amended it as   ng-pattern="/^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9\-,/-\s]*$/"

Comment: the above works , but i cannot start my string with A number but a number can come after an alphabet.

Comment: @sajanyamaha Are you using it to validate live input, to test the currently pressed key? Don't. Use it for on-submit validation. Show your current code. A https://stackblitz.com fiddle is welcome.

Comment: I changed it to on submit @WiktorStribiżew and it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments, you want to match any character but colon.

This should do the job:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!\d+$)[^:]+$/"
```

Comment: here all special characters are being rejected, only colon needs to be rejected

Comment: @sajanyamaha: Did you try it? It accept any string that is not only numeric and doesn't contain colon. Colon is the only character rejected.

Comment: @sajanyamaha: How do you use it? Show us your code.

Comment: some cahnge in requirement came in .now should allow ' , / -' and reject all other special characters so i amended it as   ng-pattern="/^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9\-,/-\s]*$/"